# php html_entity_decode and htmlspecialchars_decode not working

Tags: php, html, get, decode, html-entities

I have a preview page or an email that is created with html and php. So basically on this page there is a big $body string that can contain any html and php. But I want to send this string to another page with a link:

```
echo '<a href="[theURL]?body='.htmlentities($body).'">Click here</a>';
```

the link goes to a second php page that should display everything the same was as on the first page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["body"])){
        echo html_entity_decode($_GET["body"]);
        //echo htmlspecialchars_decode($_GET["body"]);
    }
?>
```

the second page gets the string in the url, but remain empty. so either it's not decoding it right or i missed something simple?
the url looks something like this: %20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20

%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20

Is there a better way to do this than $_GET? I tried to use a form instead of a link and use post, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: `urlencode()` is what you should actually be using. urls have length limits, so if body is large you should not use this apporach

Comment: yup i got a Request-URI Too Long error for some emails. gonna need to send the body string with something other than $_GET, and $_POST didn't seem to work :S

Comment: I tried to create a form inside the email that puts the body in a hidden input and a submit button instead of the link, but clicking it does nothing: 
   $body .= '<form method="post" action="'.$email_view.'" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="email_body" value="'.urlencode($body).'"/>
<input style="'.$email_link.'" type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here"/>
</form>';

Comment: you cant put a form in an email and im not sure ehy you are trying to

Comment: i was trying to send the body string through $_POST instead of GET, to avoid the url awkwardness. Is there another way to use POST from an email?

Comment: i think we may be using `email` in a different context. if you are just trying to send a string from one page to another, and its to large for the url, post is a good option; otherwise you need to store it locally in a db or a file at least temporarily

Comment: ok i guess ill be saving them all in the database, thanks :)